# Handling quasi-perfect separation in a zero-inflated negative binomial regression in R

Tags: r, negative-binomial-distribution, zero-inflation, separation

I want to run a zero-inflated negative binomial regression in R, but one of my variables exhibits quasi-complete separation and throws errors for both the negative binomial and logistic pieces.  I've been using the `zeroinfl()` function in the `pscl` package:

```
pop_dense_zinb <- 
   zeroinfl(thing_count ~ 
                dataset[["variable_causing_issues"]],
         data = dataset, 
         dist = "negbin", 
         EM = TRUE)
```

Errors:

```
Warning: glm.fit: fitted rates numerically 0 occurred
Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
Error in glm.fitter(x = X, y = Y, w = w, start = start, etastart = etastart,  : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in 'x'
```

What can I do (in general, and particularly in R)?  Is there an R package that can handle penalized likelihood methods like Firth in a zero-inflated negative binomial regression?  I don't want to toss this variable because it's the best predictor of the outcome, which makes a lot of sense empirically, as well.

Comment: Please edit to clarify if you are asking about how this is addressed in general, or if you're just asking for r code / packages. The latter is off topic here, but the former would be a good question for our site.

Comment: I'm interested in both what statistical method is most appropriate and how to program said method in R.  Edited!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't know of a bias-adjusted zero-inflated model (a la Firth & Kosmidis). However, it's fairly easy to combine a bias-adjusted binary regression model with a hurdle regression.

The standard `hurdle(y ~ ...)` model can also be estimated by separately calling `glm(factor(y > 0) ~ ..., family = binomial)` and `zerotrunc(y ~ ..., subset = y > 0)` (using the `countreg` package from R-Forge).

Instead of estimating the binary zero hurdle part (y = 0 vs. greater) with `glm(..., family = binomial)` you can use `brglm2` or `logistf` etc. The zero-truncated count part is not affected by this and can either be taken from `hurdle()` as before or equivalently from `zerotrunc()`.